# connect to host in C

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix

I have to connect to `host` and `port`. Port is const, but `host` variable should input from shell.
I've got an error.

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
    if (argc<2){
        printf("Need more arguments\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int sock;
    if((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0){
        perror("socket creating error");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(22222);
    addr.sin_addr.s_addr = argv[1];    // try to conect host
...
}
```

Comment: What is the error? And, what is your question?

Comment: question is how to fix that?

Comment: You need to be more specific about your error or we cannot help you.

Comment: It just doesn't connect.

Comment: What error are you getting. Every thing looks fine to me.

Comment: Did u try this  `inet_addr(argv[1]);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't assign the host to the `s_addr` like that. You need to convert it from a string host name/ip number to the correct format for `s_addr`

If you're POSIX, look at `getaddrinfo()` otherwise you can use things like `inet_addr()`,  `gethostbyname()`, `gethostbyaddr()` and so on. The key being, the need to make the conversion.

I would suggest a google for some example client/server code... there's a ton of it. Including here on SO.